# Django not appending slash to admin URL

Tags: django

I'm using Django for my project's backend, and React on the frontend. As such, I have to specify a fallback URL which serves up index.html, which contains the script for all of my frontend code.

However I want Django to match `admin` and `admin/`. The Regex below solves the problem, but accessing `admin` doesn't append a slash (I have APPEND_SLASH set to True in settings). The result is ugly looking urls like `adminapis` instead of `admin/apis` when I am using the admin interface.

Any idea how I can preserve the trailing slash?

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"admin/?", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("api.urls", namespace="api")),
    re_path(r".*", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

Comment: Did you try just `path("admin/", admin.site.urls),`? It should append slash for `/admin` url by default.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Problem with that is that `http://localhost:8000/admin` will match the fallback URL pattern

Comment: Ah, so you want `http://localhost:8000/admin` also work without slash?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner that would be ideal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url pattern should be `r"admin/"`, without the question mark, i.e. make the trailing slash mandatory.

Then verify that in your settings.py

- there is *no* `APPEND_SLASH=False` (You want the default value `True`)
- and that you have `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'` in
  the `MIDDLEWARE` tuple (needed for
  [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#append-slash)).

Now, when you enter the url `[…]/admin`, a trailing slash will automatically be added.

If you don’t remove the question mark, django will not add the trailing slash, because the url is valid without it.

Comment: hey....facing the same issue, and my url_patterns looks like
urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls),] .....and APPEND_SLASH is also True...still amy admin site is not redirecting automatically....i have to add the trailing slash manually....any idea??

Comment: You don’t possibly have APPEND_SLASH defined twice in your settings.py by accident?

Comment: Found it.....was missing the contrib.common middleware...APPEND_SLASH needs that to work.!

Comment: thanks for resolving this, will add it to the answer.